# Get nested objects values from JSON in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, object

So here is my JSON column in my Postgres DB:

```json
{
  "objekt_art": {
    "86": {
      "code": "86",
      "bezeichnung_de": "Kino",
      "bezeichnung_fr": "Cinéma",       
      "bezeichnung_it": "Cinema",
      "bezeichnung_en": null,
      "kurz_bezeichnung_de": "Kino",
      "relevant_fuer_berechnung_steuerquote": true
    },
    "27": {
      "code": "27",
      "bezeichnung_de": "Kiosk",
      "bezeichnung_fr": "Kiosque",
      "bezeichnung_it": "Chiosco",
      "bezeichnung_en": null,
      "kurz_bezeichnung_de": "Kiosk",
      "relevant_fuer_berechnung_steuerquote": true
    }
  }
}
```

I need to be able to query the bezechnung_de for example where code = 86.
The number of code i can pass from another table.

How can i for example make a query with two columns. One with the number and the second with bezeichnung_de.

Like this:

```
Code Bez
86   Kino
```

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data  model

Comment: Which datatype is used in a column `jsonb` or `json` or `text`?

Comment: Postgres 10.8 and it's a text field so i have to cast it to json or jsonb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample data structure and sample table for join data: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0cb692555802dd6ec7fd116b750af006)

```sql
select
  je.value -> 'code' as "Code",
  je.value -> 'bezeichnung_de' as "Bez"
from
  test t
  cross join jsonb_each((data::jsonb ->> 'objekt_art')::jsonb) je
  -- In table test_join I insert value 86 for join record
  inner join test_join tj on je.key::int = tj.json_id
```

Comment: `(data::jsonb ->> 'objekt_art')::jsonb` can be simplified to `data::jsonb -> 'objekt_art'`

Answer (score 2):

As you know the code, this is fairly easy:

```
select t.the_column -> 'objekt_art' -> '86' ->> 'code' as code,
       t.the_column -> 'objekt_art' -> '86' ->> 'bezeichnung_de' as bez
from the_table t
where ...
```

The value `'86'` can be a parameter. The first expression to select the code isn't really needed though, as you could replace it with the constant value (=parameter) directly.

If the "outer" JSON key isn't the same value as the `code` value, you could use something like this:

```
select o.value ->> 'code' as code, 
       o.value ->> 'bezeichnung_de' as bez
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_each(t.the_column -> 'objekt_art') o(key, value)
where o.key = '86'
  and ... other conditions ...
```

If you are using Postgres 13 or later, this can also be written as a JSON path expression:

```
select a.item ->> 'code' as code,
       a.item ->> 'bezeichnung_de' as bez
from (
  select jsonb_path_query_first(t.the_column, '$.objekt_art.* ? (@.code == "86")') as item
  from the_table t
  where ....
) a
```

All examples assume that the column is defined with the data `jsonb` which it should be. If it's not you need to cast it: `the_column::jsonb`

Comment: yes but the problem is i don't know the 86 before. I have another table that have a column (objekt_art) with the number inside. I have to be able to make some kind of join with that value and the code value.

Comment: @user2210516: you will have to compare the value `86` at some point. See my edit for alternatives. I find the JSON structure highly questionable because it repeats the same "code value" at two different locations. Accessing keys that you don't know the value for is a bit challenging. This would be all so much easier with a properly normalized data model.

Comment: yes i think i would be able to solve the problem alone if it wasnt for the double location of the numbers. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you can be sure that the duplicated values are never out of sync, the first query will work just fine.